# Unity3d - How to do transparency images?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cursor, texture2d

I have a unity application. When the user hover on the object, I want to change mouse image.So, I want to know how to make part of image transparent in unity3d? If I use directly .png image, the mouse looks like below image :

[image]

I don't want to show gray area. How can I do?

Comment: Transparency shows black when using a non transparent shader. Your image seems to be a jpg so it has no transparency. Unity does not use jpg and converts them to png but the original has no transprency anyway, it is white. You need to rework the image in Gimp or Photoshop to remove the useless grey parts.

Comment: @Everts if you write your message as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

An image file can be saved with a crowd of formats. For your arrow can have transparent areas you should save it in a format that handles the so-called "alpha channel". This channel stores information about the degree of transparency (from 0% to 100%) of all and each of the pixels. Simple programs like Windows Paint eliminate this channel. I recommend you use "Gymp", is the one I use (It's free)

If you don't have that problem. Be sure you have selected the correct Shader Type. Not all the shaders are ready to transparency. I recomend you to use the "transparent Cutout" for 3D Objects:
[image: transparent shader]

And "Sprite (2d and UI)" for 2D Objects:
[image]

Comment: I don't know gymp, is it gimp?

Comment: and I apologize for the apologi-C-e :-D

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, in the asset explorer, if you click on your .png image, you should be able to select the texture type. It is definitely possible to have textures with transparency.
You should also simple check that you saved your png image with transparency

Comment: if I select transparency, all parts of the image is be transparency. I can't see any mouse pointer.

Comment: I suppose you changed the image color. What I suggested is that you check you have the proper type of texture and shader. Look at ORParga's answer. He explain what I meant in more details

Answer (score 1):

Transparency shows black when using a non transparent shader so that is not your case. Your image seems to be a jpg so it has no transparency (RGB only).

Unity does not use jpg and converts them to png but as the original has no transparency anyway, it is white pixels in the original and white pixels in the png conversion.

You need to rework the image in Gimp or Photoshop to remove the useless grey parts and make sure you save it as png so the transparency is stored (RGBA).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I guess people could like a more modern solution for most recent Unity versions (like I did).

Unity now supports **Shaders Graphs**, which means you can create a shader that gives transparency to a selected color in an image that normaly wouldn't have an alpha channel (like jpg or gif).

Sure if you are creating the image just make a .png with alpha channel, but sometimes free assets need a little tweak (as you didn't create them):

1. Make sure you installed a render pipeline that supports the shader graph (Window -> Package Manager -> Lightweight RP)
2. Create a render pipeline in your project (Create -> Rendering -> UniversalRenderPipeline -> Forward Render)
3. Make it active (Edit-> Project Settings -> Graphics -> Scriptable Render Pipeline Settings (select the one you created)
4. Create a new shader (Create -> Shader -> Unlit Graph), I created this one with good results:
   [image: Transparent sprite shader graph]
5. Create a material, so we can actually use this shader in sprites (Create -> Material)
6. Configure the material to use the new created shader (with material selected, Shader Graphs -> [your shader name]

**And voila!**

I'm new to this shader graph thing but it looks really, really promising.

If everything went well you'll end up with a material like this:

[image: material screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I open the image in Paint 3D. Do Magic select. Cut the result and paste into a new Paint 3D project. Save as Image and tick Transparency.

Where ever its come from, and whatever format the original image, these seems to work every time.